# Why can't we have list initialization with the following syntax for set<A, Less>?

Tags: c++, c++11, c++20

I have simple sample code below.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <set>
using namespace std;

class A {

public:
   A() = default;
   A(int x) : _x(x) {}
   int getX() { return _x; }

private:
   int _x;

};

bool compare (A x, A y) {
   return x.getX()-y.getX();
}

using Less = bool (*)(A, A);

int main() {
   set <int> s1 = {1,2,3}; // <-- clause 1 - no issue!
   bool (*fnc)(A, A) = compare;
   set <A, Less> s2(fnc) = { A(1), A(2) }; // <-- clause 2. Expecting ";" at the end of declaration
   return 0;
}
```

Why can't I list initialize clause 2 while no issue on clause 1?

Comment: `(fnc)` is an initializer, and `= { A(1), A(2) }` is an initialzier. You can't have both. Something like `({A(1), A(2)}, fnc)` should work. Also an obligatory reminder that using function pointers as comparators only makes sense if you want to switch between different comparators at runtime, because of the overhead. If not, pass `std::integral_constant<decltype(&compare), compare>` as the comparator. Not only it doesn't waste memory, but also doesn't require the extra constructor argument.

Comment: Got it!. Sometimes i need another pair of eyes. Just one of those stupid thing i missed. LOL. Appreciate much.

Answer (score 3):

Try

```
template<auto x>
using val_t=
  std::integral_constant<
    decltype(x),
    x
  >;


set <A, val_t<compare>> s2 = { A(1), A(2) };
```

Your existing code initialized std set with a function pointer, then tried to initialize it again with an initializer list.  You can only initialize an object once.

Here I passed the less function via the `val_t` type, so I don't have to pass it in at initialization time.

`val_t` passed a function name produces a compile time function pointer that can be invoked with `()` (honestly due to accidental quirks in the language) and acts as a type carrying a function pointer.

It can also carry integers in a type (and that is what std integral constant was designed to carry); I am reusing it as a pointer carrier because it saves boilerplate.

Answer (score 2):

In order to be able to use a custom comparator and the initializer list, I suggest that you put your comparison function in a `class` which the `set` will then instantiate:

```cpp
struct compare {
    bool operator()(const A& x, const A& y) const {
        return x.getX() < y.getX();
    }
};

std::set<A, compare> s2 = {A(1), A(2)};
```

Note that the `getX` member function should be `const` too since it doesn't modify the object.

---

Alternatively, if you don't want to make a `class`, you can supply the pointer to the function after the initializer-list:

```cpp
bool compare(const A& x, const A& y) { return x.getX() < y.getX(); }

int main() {
    set<int> s1 = {1, 2, 3};
    set<A, decltype(&compare)> s2({A(1), A(2), A(3)}, compare);
}
```